# Return two Enum states

Tags: python

Suppose, I have

```
class State(Enum):
    TAKEPROFIT  = 1
    STOPPEDOUT  = 2
    WINNER      = 3
    LOSER       = 4
```

How can I return the combination of e.g. `State.STOPPEDOUT` and `State.LOSER` ?
The `|` does not seem to be supported:

```
return State.STOPPEDOUT | State.LOSER
```

throws

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'State' and 'State'
```

Comment: You could do that with bitmask type values, e.g. `1`, `2`, `4`, etc. but not for sequential numbers. What type would you want for this? Would a tuple or `set` suffice instead?

Comment: They can be expressed as `1 << 0`, `1 << 1` through `1 << n` and so on to make the math easier. This is a common convention in the C world when working with bit flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `IntEnum` instead of an `Enum`:

```
from enum import IntEnum


class State(IntEnum):
    TAKEPROFIT = 1
    STOPPEDOUT = 2
    WINNER = 3
    LOSER = 4
```

An `IntEnum` behaves like an `int`, so:

```
>>> State.STOPPEDOUT | State.LOSER
6
```

Comment: Any advantage over using `1, 2, 4, 8` directly?

Comment: Yes? I mean, the reason we use constants rather than magic numbers is that `State.STOPPEDOUT` means something, but what is `2`? Using enums makes your code easier to understand and maintain (just like constants in C, or similar constructs in other languages).

Answer (score 3):

While the answer by @larsks is correct, the "more" correct way to do so would be inheriting from [`IntFlag`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntFlag) (`auto()` generates powers of 2; you can use your own values if you so choose):

```py
from enum import IntFlag, auto

class State(IntFlag):
  TAKEPROFIT = auto()
  STOPPEDOUT = auto()
  WINNER = auto()
  LOSER = auto()
```

`|`, `&` and `^` operations result in instances of the same class:

```py
>>> State.STOPPEDOUT | State.LOSER
<State.STOPPEDOUT|LOSER: 10>
>>> State.STOPPEDOUT & State.LOSER
<State: 0>
>>> State.STOPPEDOUT ^ (State.LOSER | State.STOPPEDOUT | State.TAKEPROFIT)
<State.TAKEPROFIT|LOSER: 9>
```

`in` operations are also supported:

```py
>>> State.STOPPEDOUT in (State.STOPPEDOUT | State.LOSER)
True
```

`IntFlag` is a subclass of `int` and `Flag` (which is inturn a subclass of `Enum`), and therefore its instances can be used anywhere an `int` is expected:

```py
>>> State.WINNER + 9
13
```

Note that if an `IntFlag` is inverted, it returns an union of the rest of the flags instead:

```py
>>> ~State.TAKEPROFIT
<State.STOPPEDOUT|WINNER|LOSER: 14>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enums have a value attribute:

```
class State(Enum):
    TAKEPROFIT  = 1
    STOPPEDOUT  = 2
    WINNER      = 3
    LOSER       = 4

State.STOPPEDOUT.value | State.LOSER.value # 6
```

Comment: How is this answer easier than using an `IntEnum`? By using an `IntEnum` we don't need to dereference the `value` attribute, so the code is shorter (and the chances of forgetting the `.value` part are reduced to 0).

Comment: I disagree. If someone asks you which hammer they should use to drive a screw into the wall, you can actually recommend a suitable heavy hammer. Alternatively, you can of course also point out the right tool.

Comment: @Matthias That’s a horrible analogy. This answer shows it can be done with Enums, which is what the OP requested.